# Horizontal Menu with Multiple Submenus

Tags: css, html, submenu

I created a menu with multiple submenus. I've been searching for ways to make the submenus dropdown in a horizontal fashion from the original menu to the submenu, and then to the final submenu (which I can sometimes get by accident, but then I screw everything up and go back to my original horizontal menu with vertical submenus). I've tried changing them to in-line block, static, and block, but I can't force it to work. Is there an easier way? What am I missing?

```css
/* Navigation Bar Menu */

nav {
  color: #F00;
  min-width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #F00;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #CCC;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav ul ul li {
  min-width: 170px;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">Our Team</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="cardio.html">Cardiovascular</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="perfusion.html">Perfusion</a></li>
            <li><a href="ptca.html">PTCA & IABP</a></li>
            <li><a href="ecmo.html">ECMO</a></li>
            <li><a href="tavr.html">TAVR</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="bloodmanagement.html">Blood Management</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="autotransfusion.html">Autotransfusion</a></li>
            <li><a href="plateletgel.html">Platelet Gel</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="disposables.html">Disposables</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Featured Products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="inquiries.html">Employment Inquiries</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactform.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if I'm missing something, but is this what you're looking for?
https://codepen.io/will0220/pen/VMMgMb

This

```
nav ul ul li {
 display: list-item;
}
```

Needs the display property removed, display: list-item forces it into rows. Hope this helps!